# Что означает @ в symfony и как найти его идентификацию?

Tags: php, symfony

Знаю, что @ в параметрах - это идентификатор сервиса.
Но еще встречаю его при обозначении директорий в бандлах и просто папок (всякие файлы конфигов, шаблоны и т.д.). Я понимаю что это какой то идентификатор директории, но какой, и как его посмотреть?

Примеры:

```
       app_file:
            # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
            resource: '@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml'

        app:
            resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
            type:     annotation
```

///////////////////////////////

```
 public function getTemplateName()
            {
                return "@Framework/Form/search_widget.html.php";
            }
```

///////////////////////////////

```
        {% extends "@FOSUser/layout.html.twig" %}
```

///////////////////////////////

Comment: указывает на бандл

Comment: Ну то что это бандл это понятно. Но как посмотреть какая директория у бандла? Например @FOSUser/layout.html.twig - где это? Конечно через поиск по проекту я найду, но я должен как то понимать сразу,  исходя из этой строки или посмотрев на конфиг, но тогда какой конфиг?

Comment: скорее всего в папке vendor искать проект. Если у вас PHPStorm установите symfony plugin и можно будет шорткатами переходить.

Comment: Ну некоторые вещи он подцепает, но цель вопроса не как найти. Хотелось бы понять смысл, и использовать самому данный синтаксис.